# Understanding "For every $\theta \in \Theta$" in the definition of the weak consistence of an estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

The definition I have in mind is: A sequence  of estimators W_n are weakly consistent for $\theta$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall \theta \in \Theta$
$$P_{\theta}[\lvert W_n - \theta \rvert > \epsilon ] \rightarrow 0$$
I am confused about the fact that this convergence in probability is for all $\theta \in \Theta$. Or, as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Definition) puts it, "the convergence in probability must take place for every possible value of this parameter".

In my mind if $P_{\theta}[\lvert W_n - \theta \rvert > \epsilon ] \rightarrow 0$ then $W_n$ converges to $\theta$ so if I considered some other $\theta' \in \Theta$ and $\epsilon' < \theta - \theta'$ then, $\lvert W_n - \theta' \rvert >' \epsilon$ so wouldn't $P_{\theta}[\lvert W_n - \theta' \rvert > \epsilon' ] \rightarrow 1$ (I think that last step is where my error is?).

I'm looking for someone to clarify the definition or my error.

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot that one changes the measure as well, so that, for two values $t\ne s$ of the parameter $\theta$, $$P_s(|W_n-s|>\epsilon)\to0\quad \text{and}\quad P_t(|W_n-t|>\epsilon)\to0$$ is not a contradiction. A simple example is when $W_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k$ with $(X_k)$ i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $t$ under $P_t$, for every $t$ in $(0,1)$. Then the law of large numbers asserts that indeed the two convergences to $0$ mentioned above, hold. In this setting, what happens is that $P_s$ and $P_t$ are concentrated on different portions on the sample space ...

Comment: ... in the sense that there exists some disjoint events $A_t$ and $A_s$ such that $$P_t(A_t)=P_s(A_s)=1\qquad P_s(A_t)=P_t(A_s)=0$$